# Command consolidation

Tags: java, shell, scripting

I'm not sure what to tag this with, but I need help combining two commands into a single command. I've tried this with ant, but it doesn't perform as required (long story). Essentially I need

```
javac *.java
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore filename
```

To be consolodated into a single command. Preferrably something like

```
ant
```

with an external build.xml file, however after several hours fiddling with Ant I've gotten it to work but not as required (I need continuous output to stdout during runtime). I'm fine with shell scripts, clever java tricks, anything. I'll take what I can get at this point.

Comment: Linux, I'm not sure what specific version (it's a remote machine so I don't know all the specifics)

Comment: Why not `javac *.java && java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore filename`?

Comment: I could do that but I was hoping it would be possible to put that in some script file where I could call a single command (ant, ./scriptname, etc). The only absolute requirement is that it allows the java to output to stdout during runtime (so ant is out of the question).

Comment: And what is stopping you from putting those two lines in a shell script?

Comment: I've been trying to write one, I don't know anything about shell scripts though. I've been reading about them, and if I get it to work I'll answer my own question

Comment: I am not convinced ant would not work.  Did you try `<java ... output="/dev/stdout" .../>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a shell script is really a trivial matter: just copy-paste those exact two lines into a file (say you call it `myscript.sh`) and you're done. Then you can run it with `sh myscript.sh`. For added convenience add a first line that says `#!/bin/sh` (the so-called "hash-bang" incantation), issue a `chmod u+x myscript.sh`, and then you can run it as any other command: `./myscript.sh`.

BTW this turned out into a question unrelated to Java, you might retag it with a shell script-related tag.

Comment: Thanks this did exactly what I needed! I managed to write up what you said but never chmod'd so I was getting an error. I didn't expect this to become a shell-based question, but this is definitely my answer!